# Python - I AM able to change Tuple's?

Tags: python, tuples

New to Python but been trying to learn it and I came across a code snippet that I can not for the life of me figure out how it works?

In the Python command shell I am using 3.x

I create a tuple as follows

```
tupl1=1,2
```

This is fine but I tried doing the following

```
tupl1=1,2,3
```

If I now print out tupl1 it shows the updated values of (1,2,3)

I thought tuples once created you can not change them? I was expecting a compiler error when I did this but it seems to work just fine?

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You didn't change the tuple, you have created a new one.